# error call data with javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a javascript function, and the function is contained within the onclick function in the html code. when the variable "data.nik" called with a value 10.34.099 or "10AXMN.09" onclick function is not functioning properly and displays an error message. if "data.nik" worth 101011 then the onclick function can be run well.

The following javascript code

```
function tabelListPegawai(data){
    var statusPegawai;
    if (data.status==1){
        statusPegawai = 'Karyawan Tetap';
    }else if(data.status==2){
        statusPegawai = 'Karyawan Tidak Tetap';
    }
    return baris = $("<tr>\
            <td>"+data.nik+"</td>\
            <td>"+data.nama_pegawai+"</td>\
            <td>"+data.nama+"</td>\
            <td>"+data.nama_jabatan+"</td>\
            <td>"+statusPegawai+"</td>\
            <td style='text-align: center;'>\
            <a class='btn btn-small aksi_atas' rel='tooltip' title='Ubah' onclick='editPegawai("+data.id_pegawai+")'><i class='icon-edit'></i></a>\
            <a class='btn btn-small aksi_atas' rel='tooltip' title='Hapus' onclick='hapusPegawai("+data.id_pegawai+", "+data.nik+")'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>\
            </td>\
    </tr>");
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you expect to happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert the quotes around the argument

```
onclick='editPegawai(\""+data.id_pegawai+"\")'>
```